# Android: Application active

Tags: java, android, xml, interface

When the application is started there will be an icon in the status bar that shows; of the application is active. 

 
And when the application have paused the icon remains on.
 When the application is closed the Icon should disappear.

I don't have any idea how I should do this, can anybody help me..some snippets or tutorials are welcome!

Many Many Many Thanks!

Comment: "Applications" are not "started" in Android, so your question is difficult to understand. Please be much more specific about what you mean by "application", "started", "paused", and "closed".

Answer (score 0):

Official dev guide for this : [Creating Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: see Matt's answer above then to make your notifications dis/appear on the Activity's lifecycle events, or try to improve the clarity of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at the Status Bar Notifications article, then hide/show your application appropriately on onCreate/onPause/onResume/onDestroy (I'm not sure of what your rules are)

More here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle